# ActiveModel attribute type-casting before validation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How do I make attribute type-casting happen *before* validation?

In this example, I expect the attribute `delicious` to be type-cast to a boolean prior to the `inclusion` validation.

```
require "bundler/inline"
gemfile(true) do
  ruby "2.4.3"
  source "https://rubygems.org"
  gem "activemodel", "5.2.2"
  gem "actionpack", "5.2.2"
end
require "active_model"
require "action_controller"
require "minitest/autorun"

class Fruit
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Attributes
  attr_accessor :delicious, :name
  attribute :delicious, :boolean
  validates :delicious, inclusion: { in: [false, true] }
end

class TestFruit < Minitest::Test
  def test_fruit
    params = ActionController::Parameters.new(
      delicious: '1', # rails checkboxes use strings '0' or '1'
      name: 'banana'
    ).permit!
    banana = Fruit.new(params)
    banana.validate
    assert_equal [], banana.errors.full_messages
    # Fails: ["Delicious is not included in the list"]
  end
end
```

Please note that this question has nothing to do with `ActiveRecord`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `attr_accessor :delicious`. `attribute` will define the getter and setter methods.

### Some analysis:

#### `attr_accessor`

Getters and setters are defined directly on `Fruit`.

```rb
1| class Fruit
2|   attr_accessor :delicious
3| end

method = Fruit.new.method(:delicious)
method.owner # => Fruit
method.source_location # => ['/path/to/fruit.rb', 2]
```

#### `attribute`

Getters and setters are defined on an anonymous module instance that `Fruit` uses for method lookup.

```rb
1| class Fruit
2|  attribute :delicious
3| end

method = Fruit.new.method(:delicious)
mod = method.owner # => #<Module:0x00007fc583da1f60>
Fruit.ancestors.include?(mod) # => true
method.source_location # => ['/path/to/active_model/attribute_methods.rb', 36]
```

When using both `attr_accessor` and `attribute`, `Fruit` will call the more immediate getters and setters: those defined by `attr_accessor`.

```rb
1| class Fruit
2|   attr_accessor :delicious
3|   attribute :delicious
4| end

method = Fruit.new.method(:delicious)
method.owner # => Fruit
method.source_location # => ['/path/to/fruit.rb', 2]
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a custom setter

```
def delicious=(value)
  self[:delicious] = case value
  when '1', 1 then true
  when '0', 0 then false
  end
end
```

That way you'll always have a boolean (or nil).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and +1. But, I'm hesitant about this approach for two reasons. First, we know rails has a function somewhere for the coercion, so I feel like I shouldn't have to write this case statement. Second, I've already specified `attribute :delicious, :boolean` so I don't want to write this accessor method at all! Now, your answer may very well be the only way, I guess I'm just hoping another answer comes along :)